Restricting Visibility of Component Using Custom Permission Not Working
I am trying to restrict the visibility of a managed package component that is deployed as a tab on an Account record.  I have created the permission set and included a custom permission in that permission set and in the App builder created a filter to restrict visibility to anyone that does not have that permission set assigned (ie I see the custom permission and set that it must equal true to view the component).
It works in my Dev Org and the tab is hidden if the user does not have the correct permission set assigned.  Once packaged, I see all of these items (permission set, custom permission, and the custom permission assigned to the permission set) in a package installed in a Professional Edition test org abd set the filter just as I did in the Dev Org.  But the result is different in that all users can see the tab where the component is deployed regardless of being assigned the permission set or not.  Any ideas why this is occurring.  Am I missing something that needs to be done once it is packaged?

Are you getting any errors in the console?  I had an issue that may be similar.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316937/lwc-custom-permission-error-in-subscriber-org-invalid-module-id-my-namespace

No.  Nothing indicating that there is an error.  I see in the documentation on View/Edit Tab Settings in Permission Sets that ... "If a user has another permission set or profile with enabled settings for the same tab, the most permissive setting applies."
So I am speculating that there is some default general permission associated with Page > Tabs that allows users to see them by default (even when a custom tab is added by a user) and therefore overrides the restriction that I put in place but that is speculation because I am lacking another plausible explanation at this point.

Also. I am not doing this programmatically, I am trying to hide a tab on the Page > Tabs section of the Page editor by implementing a Component Visibility Filter using the custom permission from my managed package.

I figured out the problem if not the solution.  When the package is installed, all components are enabled for all Profiles, which defeats the purpose of Permission Sets since the proifiles grant permission that I am trying to limit to only certain users through the permission sets.  In another post (Limiting Custom Component Access in Managed Package) it was suggested that this happens on install of the package when the installer chooses to "Install for All Users".  I will test and update the other post with the results of testing this.
